# Xperf vs WPR differences in captured data

Tags: xperf

What are the differences between these two tools?

They are part of the same package:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/

And they are using the same API I assume, but Microsoft does not state if they have differences and details on this.

Are they equal in the captured information?
Are there some preferences in use-case scenarios when one should be preferred?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/

> The Windows Performance Toolkit consists of two independent tools: Windows Performance Recorder (WPR) and Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA). In addition, support is maintained for the previous command-line tool, Xperf. However, Xperfview is no longer supported. All recordings must be opened and analyzed by using WPA

It looks like `GPUView` still has scripts that use `Xperf`, so perhaps `Xperf` is retained as backwards compatibility for existing scripts. But `WPR` is the newer tool meant to replace "legacy Xperf"